# GTK file open dialog style

Tags: linux, windows, gtk

I've written a portable app (running on all Windows versions and recent Linux distributions) using GTK in C.

For portability reasons, I use GTK's open file dialog feature, but I found the GTK dialog highly not practical.
Is there any way to use the Operating System's own dialog style for opening / saving files within a GTK environment ?

Thanks for help.

Best regards,
Vincent.

Comment: No. Linux doesn't even *have* one, so you're either stuck with the GTK+ one or importing Qt for its or something. And there's no API for exposing the Windows API file dialogs in GTK+ itself. You could probably hack one together with some use of GDK, but I wouldn't really know how to do it well (and it would probably not play nice with the rest of GTK+)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, you can instantiate the Windows own file selection dialog, and use the Windows API to retrieve or set the file you are looking for.

"Linux" is not a platform, and thus does not have a file selection dialog. GTK+ has its own file selection dialog, just like Qt has it, or any other toolkit does.

If you value consistency across platforms, my suggestion is to use the GTK file selection dialog; you may not find it "practical", but it's pretty much well-established.

If you value consistency *with* the platform, you will have to use a specific file selection dialog on each platform you are targeting. The gedit text editor has a wrapper class that does precisely that: it uses platform-specific API depending on the platform it's running on ([MacOS](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gedit/tree/gedit/gedit-file-chooser-dialog-osx.h), and [Linux or Windows](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gedit/tree/gedit/gedit-file-chooser-dialog-gtk.h)), and wraps it with a [custom class](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gedit/tree/gedit/gedit-file-chooser-dialog.h).

Comment: Using a few platform-depending code is fine for me, as long it's not hundreds of lines of code.
Thank you for your great answer, I'll check how gedit makes it.